# Check my port sites saying port 443 is blocked but i can still access secure sites

Tags: networking, router, firewall, port-forwarding, port

I was trying to forward ports on my router and was getting port blocked even when specifying the correct rules. Then i checked and saw that every port except 80 is showing filtered or stealth in some sites.

eg. it shows port 443 as blocked but i can still access secure sites. How is this possible?

Comment: yeah thats right. But the thing is i talked to my isp and they are saying that they have open ports on their side. Could they just block incoming connections on every port except 80?

Comment: Rebooted the router? Most of that settings only works after a reboot.

Answer (score 2):

A port forwarding is used to let an external connection access your network. If you try to access a site using HTTPS it's an outbound connection.

In short you'd setup a port forwarding if you were hosting a webserver on your network, not to get out of it.